# Can't install certain php extensions

Tags: php, apache, magento, ini

I am running a `Windows 10` system with `Apache2.4.20` and `PHP7.0.6` and am currently trying to install Magento on localhost. I have been having some problems installing the PHP extensions required for Magento to run-

I have already located the `php.ini` file and removed the semicolon from the extensions, and have this already in there: `extension_dir = C:\php\ext` , so it is not a case of me uncommenting them for it to work; having uncommented them they still do not work.

The extensions I am trying to load are `PHP extension xsl` and `PHP extention gd`

Now for the second one, `PHP extension gd`, I have uncommented `extension=php_gd2.dll` but am assuming that this isnt the same as the `gd` that i want. Could you please also explain how I could go about installing this then as I cannot seem to find a line with `extension=php_gd.dll`

Thank you.

Comment: Magento is not meant to run on Windows. See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html. You should maybe consider adopting [tag:docker] or [tag:vagrant]

Comment: Or http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html because it looks like you are under Magento 2.x